# Generating combinations from two joined vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, combinatorics

I have the following code to generate all combinations from two joined vectors.

I have some restrictions:

- Exclude combinations if all members have the same "d" value
- Exclude combinations if several members have the same "s" value
- If there is only one member in the combination, I don't want all versions with "d" value, just the unique "s" value

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<string>> all_comb(const vector<string> &v, const size_t count)
{
    assert(count <= v.size());
    vector<bool> bitset(v.size() - count, 0);
    bitset.resize(v.size(), 1);

    vector<vector<string>> result;

    do {
        vector<string> tmp;
        for (size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
            if (bitset[i])
                tmp.push_back(v[i]);
        }
        result.push_back(tmp);
    } while (next_permutation(bitset.begin(), bitset.end()));

    return result;
}

void get_all_stat(vector<vector<string>> &stat, const vector<string> &s, const vector<double> &d)
{
    // add all comb without d
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= s.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<vector<string>> ret;
        ret = all_comb(s, i);
        stat.insert(stat.end(), ret.begin(), ret.end());
    }

    // generate list mixed s and d
    vector<string> tmp;
    for (const auto &i : s)
    {   
        tmp.push_back(i);
        for (const auto &j : d)
        {
            ostringstream oss;
            oss << noshowpoint << j;
            string s = oss.str();
            tmp.push_back(i + ":" + s);
        }
    }   

    // calculate all comb
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= tmp.size(); i++)
    {       
        vector<vector<string>> ret;
        ret = all_comb(tmp, i);

        for (const auto &v : ret)
        {
            unordered_map<string, unsigned> seen_s;
            unordered_map<double, bool> seen_d;

            for (const auto &s : v)
            {
                string left { s };
                double right { 0 };

                string::size_type pos { s.find(":") };

                // on a trouvé un :
                if (pos != string::npos)
                {
                    left = s.substr(0, pos);
                    right = stod(s.substr(pos + 1));
                }

                seen_s[left] += 1;
                seen_d[right] = true;
            }

            // we dont want combination with all same "d"
            if (seen_d.size() <= 1)
                continue;

            // we dont want combination with more than one "s"
            bool add { true };
            for (const auto &m : seen_s)
            {
                if (m.second > 1)
                {
                    add = false; 
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (add)
                stat.push_back(v);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> s { "a", "b" };
    vector<double> d { 2.5, 3.7 };

    vector<vector<string>> stat;
    get_all_stat(stat, s, d);

    for (const auto &i : stat)
    {
        for (const auto &j : i)
            cout << " " << j;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Wanted output (order is not important):

```
b
a
a b
a:3.7 b:2.5
a:3.7 b
a:2.5 b:3.7
a:2.5 b
a b:3.7
a b:2.5
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4209a1cac1590449)

Actual performance:

With small `s` and `d` vectors it works well but if I had more values to the vectors it eat lots of memory.

With a `s` vector of 6 elements and `d` vector of 4 elements my system kill the process after eating more than 10Go of memory.

How could I optimize this?

Comment: The example does not produce the outputs `"a:2.5"`,  `"a:3.7"`, `"b:2.5"` and `"b:3.7"`. Is this intentional?

Comment: @hoffmale yes i dont want combination with several member having the same `s` value, so here there is two member with `a:` and two with `b:`

Comment: I meant those as 4 separate results (i.e. would correspond to 4 lines of output), so there are no duplicates. The example only produces string+double combinations if both `"a"` and `"b"` are present, but not with just either of those.

Comment: @hoffmale ha ok, yes it is normal, if there is only one member in the combination i dont want all version with `:...` just the unique `s` value. sorry if i my english is not so clear.

Comment: nobody can help me ? :(

Comment: Sorry, don't have time for a complete review right now. But basically, you can improve performance a lot by only generating combinations that contain each string in `s` at most once (\$(d + 2)^{s}\$ total before filtering), instead of the current power-set approach (\$2^{(d + 1) * s}\$ total before filtering). This reduces the amount of generated combinations from \$2^{30} = 1073741824\$ to just \$6^6 = 46656\$ for 6 elements in `s` and 4 in `d` (before filtering).

Comment: @hoffmale: i have updated the version: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/908093aa780430b8, it seems a lot better. thanks for your help